# I got this error when I publish my gem: "Could not find gem 'uix_validations (~> 0.5.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I just publish my gem at rubygems.org, [here is the link](https://rubygems.org/gems/uix_validations/). Everything looks nice.

But when I try to add to a project with `gem 'uix_validations', '~> 0.5.0'`, I got this error at bundle install:

```
Could not find gem 'uix_validations (~> 0.5.0)' in any of the gem sources listed
in your Gemfile
```

And I have no idea how to fix this.

I published using this steps:

```
gem build uix_validations.gemspec
```

This generate a file: `uix_validations-0.5.0.gem`

And to publish:

```
gem push uix_validations-0.5.0.gem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer here: [github rubygems](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2398)

*"Your gem has been published but you need to wait for RubyGems.org to refresh it's cache. It should only take a short while."*

by: [colby-swandale](https://github.com/colby-swandale)

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a correct source in your Gemfile.

Before you specify the gem you should defined the source for rubygems. This is often done in the first row.

Example

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'uix_validations'
```

Comment: @LucasAndrade could you include the content of your gemfile in your question?